# linux antivirus software

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, anti-virus

Which antivirus software on Linux is most popular?

Comment: Not an exact answer but most Linux systems do not have (to use) anti-virus software.

Comment: Be sure to understand, what kinds of threads are most dangerous to linux machines. Security differs from Windows (and Mac). A good starting point to read would maybe be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The **MOST popular** one is **Avast**

  ---
- These are the **popular Anti-virus**

> **1)** 
>   [AVG Anti-Virus Free Edition](http://free.avg.com/download?prd=afl)
>
> **2)** 
>   [Avast! antivirus Home Edition](http://www.avast.com/eng/download-avast-for-linux-edition.html)
>
> **3)** 
>   [Panda Antivirus](http://www.pandasoftware.com/download/linux/linux.asp)
>
> **4)** 
>   [Avira AntiVir Personal](http://www.free-av.com/en/download/download_servers.php)
>
> **5)** 
>   [Clam AntiVirus](http://www.clamav.net/download/)

---

- The below image is a general overview of anti-virus in all platforms

[image]

Comment: These aren't all for Linux though...

Comment: All the 5 anti-virus listed are for Linux I just googled once again and cross-checked. I have updated my answer with links

Comment: I was talking about the pie chart, but I have just noticed that you said it was for all platforms - sorry if that was there before my first comment

Comment: @starofale Its ok, by the way it was there before you commented

Comment: @subanki: Woah, I didn't know that they all had Linux builds, thanks for the info. But one question rises: Do they have *real* (not plenty, but they exist) Linux-Viruses in their databases, or just Windows?

Comment: @Bobby After a quick Google search, Clam, avast and AVG have Linux virus databases, but don't know about others. By the way Linux has more Anti-virus that i haven't listed like Bit-Defender, Kaspersky etc. But they are not so famous in Linux world

Answer (score 6):

Probably [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/), but you don't need that for desktop usage. The typical reason ClamAV or other AV software gets installed to Linux/Unix is that someone needs to protect all those Windows boxes in the network -- ClamAV usually scans the file shares, e-mails and so on for Windows viruses.

If you're paranoid, you most likely want to scan your Ubuntu with [chkrootkit](http://chkrootkit.org/) and/or [rkhunter](http://rkhunter.sf.net/) instead, and setup [AIDE](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~rammer/aide.html) or some other intrusion detection software. But for most of us that's really overkill (for now, at least).

Answer (score 3):

The biggest one is [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/).